# Attribute name in variable

Tags: java

;How can I use the value of a String variable as attribute or method name?

Want to do something like that:

```
class Person {
    public String firstname;
}

String myAttributeName="firstname";
Person obj = new Person();
String firstNameOfObj = obj.{myAttributeName};
```

Comment: Use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). Java is not Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you *really* want to do this, you could use reflection:

```
Person obj = new Person();
Method method = Person.class.getMethod("getFirstname");
String firstname = method.invoke(obj);
```

but as mentioned in the comments, you better use a map to hold attribute values:

```
class Person {
   private Map<String,Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();

   public void setAttribute(String attr, Object value)
   {
      attrs.put(attr,vaue);
   }

   public Object getAttribute(String attr)
   {
      attrs.get(attr);
   }

}

Person person = new Person();
person.setAttribute("firstname","patrick");
String firstname = (String)person.getAttribute("firstname");
```